# How to draw a sequence of objects moving on windows form

Tags: c#

I've created the object that moves horizontally across the form in c#. Now I have to draw multiple(not one object as i have done before) objects generated randomly and moving in sequence across the form.

Here is my code that moves the object

```
private Rectangle Enemy1 = new Rectangle(0, 150, 40, 40);

//code below paints the object on the form
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, Enemy1);

//part below moves the object on the form
int EX1 = Enemy1.Location.X;
int EY1 = Enemy1.Location.Y;
Enemy1.Location = new Point(EX1 += 10, EY1 += 0);
```